# body::after pseudo element issue

Tags: pseudocode

In my css. . .

```
body {
    visibility:hidden;
}

body::after {
    visibility:visible;
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

The ::after pseudo has no effect.  Am I making an error that I don't see, or is something wrong with the implementation in Firefox, Chrome?

Comment: Did you give your after element a `display: block`, `width`, `height` and `content: ''`?

Comment: "display:block" yes, but neither width nor height.  I don't see where they are necessary?  Just tried adding them.  Makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

See this fiddle and play around with it to see what attributes are necessary:

```css
body {
  visibility: hidden;
}

body::after {
  visibility: visible;
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  content: '';
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<body>
</body>
```